# css not selector not working, not sure why

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to use the css not selector but not having much success. I am trying to apply attributes to images except for those in a .sponsors class.

```
img:not(.sponsors) {
width: initial;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

However it's applying the attributes to all images. The images in a sponsor class are in a table

```
<table class="sponsors" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-style: dotted;" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 50%;"><img src="image1.jpg" /></td>
<td style="width: 50%;"><img src="image2.jpg" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Perhaps it's being overridden by WordPress' CSS rules? Have you tried increasing the specificity of your rule? Have you checked the developer tools to see if your rule is being applied at all?

Comment: I checked and only the width:initial is applying

Comment: The try increasing the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: but sponsor is defind in the table not the img

Comment: adding the class to the images did the trick, I thought it would still apply to the images If it was done in the table

Answer (score 0):

If you are using :

```
img:not(.sponsors) {
}
```

The "sponsors" class must be in an img tag.
In your example it should be :

```
<table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-style: dotted;" border="0"> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
<td style="width: 50%;"><img  class="sponsors" src="image1.jpg" /></td> 
<td style="width: 50%;"><img  class="sponsors" src="image2.jpg" /></td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table>
```

Simple test for that : https://jsfiddle.net/c31nq2dh/

Try to move the class property and observe the result

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity I've changed the CSS rule to `border: solid 5px red;` just to see where it gets applied.

The [CSS :not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector works on elements which have the class. See only the element which does not have the class `sponsors` gets the `red colored border`

```css
img:not(.sponsors) {
    border: solid 5px red;
}
```

```html
  <table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-style: dotted;" border="0">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td style="width: 50%;"><img  class="sponsors" src="image1.jpg" /></td>
  <td style="width: 50%;"><img src="image2.jpg" /></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

But your HTML has the class `sponsors` on the parent element. Add whatever rules you need to set or reset on the images like so:

```css
.sponsors img {
    border: solid 5px red;
}
```

```html
<table class="sponsors" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-style: dotted;" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 50%;"><img src="image1.jpg" /></td>
<td style="width: 50%;"><img src="image2.jpg" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```